# Is there a way to not expand one column while expanding others?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a with users, the groups they belong to, and two columns I want to expand (below). I want to expand it so that each user keeps the groups that they're in but for each group they're in gets all possible permutations of country and season.

| User_ID | Group | Country | Season |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | France | Autumn |
| 2 | 2 | Spain | Summer |
| 1 | 2 | Italy | Winter |
| 3 | 2 | Italy | Spring |

Currently I'm expanding all of the columns then doing a semi-join to the table to drop all of the user and group combinations which don't exist.

```
df <- data.frame(User_ID = c(1, 2, 1, 3), 
    Group = c(1,2,2,1), 
    Country = c("France", "Spain", "Italy","Italy"), 
    Season = c("Summer", "Autumn", "Winter", "Spring")) 

df %>% 
    expand(User_ID, Group, Country, Season) %>%
    semi_join(df, by = c("User_ID", "Group")
```

Is this the most efficient way to do this, or am I missing something with the expand function?

Comment: can you give us an example of your desired output?

Comment: @pluke I don't know how to without the table being huge. Basically for each user-group combination that exists within the data I want them to have every permutation of country and season. The code chunk included should also give the desired output, I'm mostly wondering if I'm missing something obvious with the expand function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want (4 user/groups x 3 countries x 4 seasons, i.e. 48 rows)?

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~User_ID, ~Group, ~Country, ~Season,
  1, 1, "France", "Autumn",
  2, 2, "Spain", "Summer",
  1, 2, "Italy", "Winter",
  3, 2, "Italy", "Spring"
) |> 
  complete(nesting(User_ID, Group), Country, Season)

#> # A tibble: 48 × 4
#>    User_ID Group Country Season
#>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr> 
#>  1       1     1 France  Autumn
#>  2       1     1 France  Spring
#>  3       1     1 France  Summer
#>  4       1     1 France  Winter
#>  5       1     1 Italy   Autumn
#>  6       1     1 Italy   Spring
#>  7       1     1 Italy   Summer
#>  8       1     1 Italy   Winter
#>  9       1     1 Spain   Autumn
#> 10       1     1 Spain   Spring
#> # … with 38 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Nesting is the key, thank you!